# Querying a mysql database fetching words with a regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm using a regexp for fetching a set of words that accomplish the next syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^[dcqaahii]{5}$'
```

My first impression gave me the sensation that it was good till I realized that some letters were used more than contained in the regexp.

The question is that I want to get all words (i.e. of 5 letters) that can be formed with the letters within the brackets, so if I have two 'a' resulting words can have no 'a', one 'a' or even two 'a', but no more.

What should i add to my regexp for avoiding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If possible, this won't be easy.  This is not the kind of task that regexes are well-suited for.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you expect to match & what you don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better to retrieve all candidates first and post-process, as others have suggested:

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word REGEXP '^[dcqahi]{5}$'
```

However, nothing is stopping you from doing multiple REGEXPs.  You can select 0, 1, or 2 incidences of the letter 'a' with this grungy expression:

```
'^[^a]*a?[^a]*a?[^a]*$'
```

So do the pre-filter first and then combine additional REGEXP requirements with AND:

```
SELECT * FROM words
  WHERE word REGEXP '^[dcqahi]{5}$'
    AND word REGEXP '^[^a]*a?[^a]*a?[^a]*$'
    AND word REGEXP '^[^i]*i?[^i]*i?[^i]*$'
```

**[edit]** As an afterthought, I have inferred that for the non-vowels you also want to restrict to 0 or 1 occurrance.  So if that's the case, you'd keep going...

```
    AND word REGEXP '^[^d]*d?[^d]*$'
    AND word REGEXP '^[^c]*c?[^c]*$'
    AND word REGEXP '^[^q]*q?[^q]*$'
    AND word REGEXP '^[^h]*h?[^h]*$'
```

Yuck.

Comment: If you were able to sort the characters in the word your expression would be much easier: `word REGEXP '^a?a?c?d?h?i?i?q?$'` (you'd still need to do the 5-character regexp first)

Comment: INCREDIBLE!!!!!  Exactly what I was looking for. Could you please explain me how the REGEXP '^[^a]*a?[^a]*a?[^a]*$' works? I need to know the way I can adapt it for every case.

Comment: No worries.  The part `[^a]*` matches "zero or more of any character except 'a'".  The part `a?` matches "zero or one of the character 'a'".  So this expression works by allowing up to two optional 'a's to appear anywhere within text containing absolutely anything else.  This seems liberal, but it acts as a restriction on your original filter which has already ignored strings containing characters that you don't want.  You must bracket the entire expression with `^` and `$` so that it matches the whole string instead of just part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I can think of would be to use the above SQL you have to get an initial filtered set of data but then loop through it and further filter with some server side code (PHP etc.) which is better suited to doing that kind of logic.

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions, square brackets [] are merely a character class, like a list of allowed characters. Specifying the same letter twice within the brackets is therefore redundant.

For example the pattern `[sed]` will match `sed`, and `seed` because `e` is part of the allowed characters. Specifying a character count afterward in braces {} is merely a total count of characters previously allowed by the character class.

The pattern `[sed]{3}` therefore will match `sed` but not `seed`.

I would recommend moving the logic for testing the validity of words from SQL into your program.